# How to create GUI widget in a non-main thread

Tags: python, sockets, pyqt5

I have a simple server-client chat program in which I use threads to recieve data from server in the background. The problem is when client recieves a message a new tab for the chat has to be created. But I recieve data in a thread so I can check data and create one in a thread. Except that I can't create a widget and set its parent my window because my window is in the main thread. So it looks like this:

```
class MainWindow(QWidget):
    ...
        def addChatTab(self, nick, target, parent):
            tab = ChatTab(target)
            tab.setParent(parent)  #where I get the eror
            self.chatTabWidget.addTab(tab, nick)
            self.chatTabs[nick] = tab


class ServerManagement():
    ...
    def clientLoop(self): #runs in a different thread
        ...
        if sender == settingsManager.getUserNick():
            targetTab = receiver
        else:
            targetTab = sender

        if targetTab in mainWindow.chatTabs.keys():   #if tab is already there
            mainWindow.getChatTab(targetTab).write(message)
        else:
            mainWindow.addChatTab(targetTab, sender, mainWindow)     #create and add it to QTabWidget
            mainWindow.getChatTab(targetTab).write(message)
```

Error:

```
QObject::setParent: Cannot set parent, new parent is in a different thread
```

I understand how and why that happens but I just don't have solution for it. Can someone help me?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: @eyllanesc since my code is really messed up and unorganized, it would take half of the code to reproduce the problem. All I need is a way to be able to create a widget and set its parent a QWidget in another thread.

Comment: You should not create the GUI in another thread, what you should do is send the information to the GUI thread through signals

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not modify (understand also create) the GUI from another thread, the idea is to send the information of the secondary thread through signals for it we can make ServerManagement inherit from QObject so that it can create the signals and in a common scope between an object of ServerManagement and MainWindow to make the connection:

```
class MainWindow(QWidget):
    # ...
    def addChatTab(self, nick, target, parent):
        tab = ChatTab(target)
        tab.setParent(parent)  #where I get the eror
        self.chatTabWidget.addTab(tab, nick)
        self.chatTabs[nick] = tab

    def foo_function(self, another_args)
       # ... foo function is the method where you create the Server Management object
       self.management = ServerManagement()
       self.management.targetChanged.connect(self.update_gui)
       #
    @pyqtSlot(str)
    def update_gui(self, targetTab):
        if targetTab in self.chatTabs.keys():   #if tab is already there
            self.getChatTab(targetTab).write(message)
        else:
            self.addChatTab(targetTab, sender, self)     #create and add it to QTabWidget
            self.getChatTab(targetTab).write(message)

class ServerManagement(QObject):
    targetChanged = pyqtSignal(str)
    def __init__(self, others_arguments):
        super(ServerManagement, self).__init__()
        # ...

    def clientLoop(self): #runs in a different thread
        # ...
        if sender == settingsManager.getUserNick():
            targetTab = receiver
        else:
            targetTab = sender
        self.targetChanged.emit(targetTab)
```

Comment: I get the error `AttributeError: 'PyQt5.QtCore.pyqtSignal' object has no attribute 'connect'` at `self.management.targetChanged.connect(self.update_gui)`

Comment: @mbilal25tr Have you made ServerManagement inherit from QObject?

Comment: Yes. I checked again and I have `class ServerManagement(QtCore.QObject):` and in init `super().__init__()`

Comment: @mbilal25tr I think there is something that you have not implemented, you should not have that problem so you should provide an MCVE

Comment: I googled the error and moving `self.management.targetChanged.connect(self.update_gui)` outside the init worked. I only had to solve a couple errors of my own code. Thanks!